# Will a LensCoat BodyGuard CB fit a Canon EOS 1000D?

Tags: equipment-recommendation, equipment-protection, accessories, lenscoat

I'd like to buy a [LensCoat BodyGuard](http://www.lenscoat.com/bodyguard-clear-backreg-p-1036.html?osCsid=horzsvbxx) for my Canon EOS 1000D.

I'm in doubt because my model isn't listed in that page, so I wonder if it fits it or no. Any experience?

Then, I live in Italy, so I can't buy it anyway on amazon.com because it gets too expensive. Do you know any other good online shop for such things?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like you want a [BodyGuard Compact](http://www.lenscoat.com/bodyguard-compact-clear-backreg-p-1180.html?osCsid=horzsvbxx).

Comment: That's the one he needs. I am going on how it will not fit and yaddy yadda and there it is right on the same website :-)

Comment: Oh, cool, thanks : D
But... do you know any other shop? From their website with the shipping cost it costs me more than 60$ :\

Comment: I bet with some quick searching you could find many online stores that carry it.

Comment: Any shipments from the US/Canada will be very expensive. $30 is cheap! Alternatively you could find a supplier in the EU but for all the trouble you might save your self $10.  I find pretty much everything is more expensive in the EU so even if you find this item it might end up costing about the same after shipping.

Comment: Have you looked at amazon.co.uk?

Answer (score 0):

Didn't even know this existed...  I think it **might not fit correctly** as the listed camera bodies are larger then then EOS 1000D (Rebel XS, Kiss F) body. It also has the opening for the digital display on top of the camera which the Rebels don't have.